# Find jars containing a class file in Maven project

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

As the header says I wonder if there is such an opportunity in Maven to know the jar a class file gets loaded in a module. Just like dependency:tree, but I would like to see jars with a specific class file. Thanks!

Comment: On the Maven Central you can do a search via http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav or are you talking about your local cache $HOME/.m2/repository or within a repository manager ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm talking about the case when you have a multi-module Maven project and you would like to search for all possible locations in all jars the project depends on for a specific class file. So it should load all jars I guess and do a search if it is possible

Comment: I would use my IDE for such things?

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess my question was formulated too poor, sorry. But yes, Intellij IDEA can do this kind of things, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no specific Maven plugin (3.0+) that will search dependencies for class declarations. However, I believe I understand your need and offer the following solutions:

**Finding duplicate declarations**

```
mvn dependency:analyze-duplicate -DcheckDuplicateClasses
```

**Find containing JAR within Eclipse**

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the **Open Type** dialog. Entering part or the whole class name presents a list of containing JARs on the build classpath.

**Find containing JAR without IDE**

If more programatic control is required for checking on systems without an IDE, say a CI server, the following snippets can be used to list JAR files containing a specific class or even a specific name pattern. This approach uses Maven's dependency plugin to collect all dependencies in a temporary directory such that they may be easily searched.

*For Unix or Git Bash systems*

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/temp
for j in target/temp/*.jar; do jar -tf $j | grep SomeClass && echo $j; done
```

*For Windows via `cmd` shell*

```
mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/temp
for /R %G in (target\temp\*.jar) do @jar -tf "%G" | find "SomeClass" && echo %G
```

In either case, a matching entry's full package and class name will be displayed followed by the containing JAR file name. `grep` and `find` search parameters can be further refined to restrict matches as needed, such as `SomeClass.class`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was the thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipRego -- The error message tells you all you need to know. The commands above are Maven commands and expect a Maven project; in other words, the existence of a ``pom.xml``. If you do have a Maven project, make sure that you run said commands in the project directory..

Comment: "for j in target..." - Legend.